# IBM Data Catalog doesn't show preview for connection for Cloudant Database

Tags: ibm-data-catalog

I created a connection to Cloudant Service.

When i open the connection asset in catalog, i don't get any preview. Is this expected behaviour?

and why Download and Add to Project are disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the connection asset directly which doesn't have a preview.  You are only able to edit the connection by clicking on the edit link below.

If you created a data asset that uses the cloudant connection (pointing to a cloudant document for instance), you will then be able to preview the asset.

For a connection asset, we do not allow download or preview.  You need to be creating a data asset for those operations.